# Когортный анализ с pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Есть таблица с данными вида

```
user_id, month, year, num1, num2, type_id, type_name

12345, 04, 2019, 0, 1, 111, data1
13245, 04, 2019, 0, 1, 111, data1
14235, 05, 2019, 1, 2, 112, data2
15423, 03, 2019, 0, 1, 112, data2
```

Нужно провести когортный анализ, чтобы результат получился таким:

```
month, year, num1, type_name, total_users_on_num1

4, 2019, 0, data1, 234
4, 2019, 1, data1, 365
...
4, 2019, 0, data2, 835
4, 2019, 1, data2, 927
...
```

Выгрузка должна быть по **type_name** с количеством пользователей на каждом **num1**. 
Когорта здесь – *month*, при котором **num1 = 1**.

Есть ощущение, что здесь нужна группировка и сортировка по остальным показателям, но не могу понять, в каком порядке и по каким именно столбцам что применять.

*df.groupby('type_name').count()* дает counts, но превращает остальные столбцы в эти же counts. Кажется, что нужно сгруппировать по *type_name* – но дальше неясно, нужно ли группировать по *month*, потому что если бы здесь была множественная вложенная группировка, то получилась бы сводная таблица, а в конечной таблице на каждой строке есть данные (показатели *month* и *year* не 1 раз указаны, а для каждой строки).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут нужно использовать "оконный" запрос - не уверена, как это будет через pandas, но на чистом sql будет примерно следующее:

```
select t.month, t.year, t.num1, t.type_name, count(t.user_id) over (partition by t.type_name) as total_users_for_num1 from table t order by t.num1;
```

Comment: Так действительно короче, чем в питоне, спасибо!

Comment: Здорово) если ответ действительно помог, отметьте его, пожалуйста, как подходящий. И если плюсанете рейтинг, тоже будет приятно)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так (где df - переменная, указывающая на ваш датафрейм):

```
df.groupby(["month", "year", "num1", "type_name"]). nunique()[['user_id']].reset_index().rename(columns={'user_id': 'total_users_on_num1'})
```

reset_index тут нужен для разворачивания обратно в табличку сгруппированных данных с составным индексом; `nunique` будет правильней использовать вместо `count`, потому что скорее всего пользователи могут повторяться; rename для красоты.

Comment: да, это очень похоже на то, что нужно! А в дальнейшем, получается, нужно отсортировать данные без user_id, чтобы они ушли в count и посчитались все юзеры?
И далее удалить ненужные столбцы (или правильной практикой будет сделать новую таблицу, выгрузив нужные столбцы из этой?)